# How can I manage 2 different states in my createContext() and createContext().Provider?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, use-context

I have 2 states, one is `const [users, setUsers]`, other one is `const [horizontalDiscussion, setHorizontalDiscussion]`

users, setUsers parts are working, but not the horizontalDiscussion, and setHorizontalDiscussion.
May be cause of doing it in the same context as `useContext(UserContext)` ?
I dont know where i am doing wrong. Can you help me please?

in MainScreen.js i just write this

```
     const [users, setUsers] = useContext(UserContext);
     const [horizontalDiscussion, setHorizontalDiscussion] = useContext(UserContext);
```

Here is the UserContextManager.js

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from 'react';
import HorizontalCircles from "../components/HorizontalDiscussion";
import HorizontalDiscussion from "../components/HorizontalDiscussion";

export const UserContext = createContext();


function UserContextManager(props) {
  // if i write const {users, setUsers} then i should UserContext.Provider value={{users,setUsers}}
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([
    <HorizontalCircles
      skeleton={true}
      key={0}
      colorFirst={'rgb(' + 100 + ',' + 100 + ',' + 100 + ')'}
      colorSecond={'rgb(' + 100 + ',' + 100 + ',' + 100 + ')'}
    />,
    <HorizontalCircles
      skeleton={true}
      key={1}
      colorFirst={'rgb(' + 100 + ',' + 100 + ',' + 100 + ')'}
      colorSecond={'rgb(' + 100 + ',' + 100 + ',' + 100 + ')'}
    />,
  ]);

  const [horizontalDiscussion, setHorizontalDiscussion] = useState([
    <HorizontalDiscussion 
      skeleton={true} 
      key={0} 
      color={"rgb(" + 100 + "," + 100 + "," + 100 + ")"} 
    />,
    <HorizontalDiscussion 
      skeleton={true} 
      key={1} 
      color={"rgb(" + 100 + "," + 100 + "," + 100 + ")"} 
    />,

  ]);

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={[users, setUsers, horizontalDiscussion, setHorizontalDiscussion]}>
      {props.children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default UserContextManager;
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how they are not working ? What's the behaviour you're getting and what did you expect ?

Comment: I expected them to do their special things which i assigned. I mean there is different role for each state. But when i added other state `HorizontalDiscussion` it does what other state do. But its role is different actually, it just didnt see its role, it does what `users , setUsers` state do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use object destructuring rather than array destrucutring to get the value of context:

```
const {users, setUsers, horizontalDiscussion, setHorizontalDiscussion} = useContext(UserContext);
```

Comment: That worked!!! Thanks a million. So if i want to manage more than one state in my Context, i have to do object destructuring?  array destructuring is only used when i want to manage one state? is it right Mr

Comment: No. Always use object destructuring to get context value. array destructuring is required if you're using useReducer.

Comment: I didnt know this before. Could you please show me how i could do this with useReducer() ? And which is better?

Comment: Thank you for your help. Btw is there anyway to contact with you, i mean if i cant find answer on google, i could ask you the questions related react, react-native,

Comment: I just created a topic on which I'll be sharing ideas on React, etc. https://link.getangle.app/ZjMwon2ikJnCBmCv7

Comment: Hello, can u look at this question please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67803786/how-can-i-reach-the-variable-which-i-named-global-from-globalcontext

Answer (score 0):

i read your code if feel your state name and importer name is same maybe then occur error
please try

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from 'react';
import HorizontalCircles from "../components/HorizontalDiscussion";
import HorizontalDiscussion from "../components/HorizontalDiscussion";
export const UserContext = createContext();
function UserContextManager(props) {
// if i write const {users, setUsers} then i should UserContext.Provider value= 
{{users,setUsers}}
 const [users, setUsers] = useState([
 <HorizontalCircles
  skeleton={true}
  key={0}
  colorFirst={'rgb(' + 100 + ',' + 100 + ',' + 100 + ')'}
  colorSecond={'rgb(' + 100 + ',' + 100 + ',' + 100 + ')'}
/>,
 <HorizontalCircles
  skeleton={true}
  key={1}
  colorFirst={'rgb(' + 100 + ',' + 100 + ',' + 100 + ')'}
  colorSecond={'rgb(' + 100 + ',' + 100 + ',' + 100 + ')'}
/>,
]);
 const [horizontalDiscussiontest, setHorizontalDiscussiontest] = useState([
 <HorizontalDiscussion 
  skeleton={true} 
  key={0} 
  color={"rgb(" + 100 + "," + 100 + "," + 100 + ")"} 
 />,
 <HorizontalDiscussion 
  skeleton={true} 
  key={1} 
  color={"rgb(" + 100 + "," + 100 + "," + 100 + ")"} 
 />,

 ]);
  return (
 <UserContext.Provider value={[users, setUsers, horizontalDiscussiontest, 
  horizontalDiscussiontest]}>
  {props.children}
 </UserContext.Provider>
);
}export default UserContextManager;
```

Comment: Thank you for replying Mr. But i didnt understand what you suggested me, sorry. Btw the other person who replied solved my issue